# How do I pass a 2D array from JavaScript into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am working on a school project that involves extracting product data from multiple online retailers using various APIs/AJAX calls, and then sorting this data in PHP (I use one AJAX call for each retailer). A snippet of the code I am working on is shown below. I cannot figure out how to

1. Push a temporary array containing product attributes ("Average", "Price", "Name", "Url", and "Image") for each product into a master array (array of arrays) and then
2. Post this master array to PHP in such a way that I can index the values in it for sorting purposes.

```
function get_results() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var master_array = [];
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http//:www.source1.com",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('product').each(function() {
          var Average = $(this).find('Average').text();
          var Price = $(this).find('Price').text();
          var Name = $(this).find('Name').text();
          var Url = $(this).find('Url').text();
          var Image = $(this).find('Image').text();
          master_array.push([Average, Price, Name, Url, Image]);
        });
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http//:www.source2.com",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('product').each(function() {
          var Average = $(this).find('Average').text();
          var Price = $(this).find('Price').text();
          var Name = $(this).find('Name').text();
          var Url = $(this).find('Url').text();
          var Image = $(this).find('Image').text();
          master_array.push([Average, Price, Name, Url, Image]);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the example code for JQuery ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Here is an example code:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Your updated function can look like this:

```
function get_results() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var master_array = [];
    $(xml).find('product').each(function() {
        var Average = $(this).find('Average').text();
        var Price = $(this).find('Price').text();
        var Name = $(this).find('Name').text();
        var Url = $(this).find('Url').text();
        var Image = $(this).find('Image').text();
        master_array.push([Average, Price, Name, Url, Image]);
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http//:www.source1.com",
      data: master_array,
      success: function(response) {
        alert('Data successfully posted');
      },
     fail: function(response) {
        alert('Data could not be posted');
      }
    });

  });
}
```

In the above code the success and fail are functions that are called when the servers returns a response. If the response was correctly sent then the success function is called. If there was an error on the server then the fail function is called.